# how to set data for UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipickerview

I am tryign to add a PickerView - But I see a black screen... What am I doing wrong???

```
UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];

    [self.view addSubview:myPickerView];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement the [UIPickerViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html) methods:

```
– numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
– pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:
```

and the [UIPickerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html) method:

```
– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:
```

Don't forget to set the properties:

```
UIPickerView * myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:myPickerView];
```

And in the .h file, remember to put:

```
<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

I usually use an `NSMutableArray` filled with strings in order to fill in the data. Hope that helps!